# How to get route parameters after refresh page?

Tags: angular

I can not get route parameters after refresh page

I have tried listen `ActivatedRoute`

```
this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);
});
```

Route url is:

```
{
    path: "dictionary",
    component: SkeletonComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ":dictType",
            component: DictionaryComponent
        },
        {
            path: ":dictType/:code",
            component: VersionsComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get both parameters:

**:dictType/:code**

When I open page by URL:

```
/dictionary/Position/1
```

I can not get `dictType` as `Position` and `:code` as `1`

Comment: Certanly works without braces

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realized I had messed up. But that did help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
let params = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params
console.log(params)
```

Comment: put it inside ngonInit

Answer (score 1):

Try using `activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('dictType')` && `activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('code')`

Comment: This works only when I user route click in Angular, not refresh